# Maximizer for a function when constraint is set to $0$

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm solving a problem where I'm asked to maximize the function $xy$ and it's subject to the condition $x+y\leq0$.

Can I get $0$ as the maximizer for these problems?

Comment: @MathLover- I just have one constrained...which is x+y is less than equal to 0.

Comment: They you will not have a maximum. I can have $x + y = - 500$ and have $x = y = -250$ so $xy \gt 0$. Now I can also have $x + y = - 10000, x = y = -5000$. Now new $xy$ is greater than old $xy$.... there is no maximum.

Comment: @MathLover-thanks so much. can you tell me what happens when we want to maximize "xy" subject to x+y^2 is less than equal to 0?

Comment: Did you mean $x + y^2 \leq 0$?

Comment: yes so the entire problem: maximize f(x,y)=xy
subject to  x+y square is less than equal to 0, and x and y both are greater than equal to 0

Comment: It is the same - no maximum, because $y^2$ will be positive but $y$ can take negative values and so $xy$ can be positive.